# When should I prefer readIO over read? (or vice-versa)

Tags: haskell

I was trying to grok the tradeoffs in picking `readIO` over `read`, and I wrote these 2 snippets

```
> map read . words <$> getLine :: IO [Int]
1 2 a
[1,2,*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
> mapM readIO . words =<< getLine :: IO [Int]
1 2 a
*** Exception: user error (Prelude.readIO: no parse)
```

I understand that throwing exceptions in pure code (just like `read` does) is often bad, but usually I always use read inside the IO monad, and thus I should be able to catch the exception almost always.

`readIO` isn't used in as many snippets/examples/tutorials from what I've seen, but otoh carrying the possibility for error in the type seems a good thing, and collecting all the `Read a` in a single IO with `mapM` yields the errors earlier than the first example with plain `map`. Failing fast is usually a coveted property.

Should I go around and replace all the `read`s with `readIO`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `readIO` is evil. Like `read` it should be considered a partial function. `read` is fine (more or less) if you make sure that parse failure can never happen, or if you just check out some stuff in GHCi.

If you properly want to catch parse failure, then make that *properly* explicit, don't just chuck it it the `IO` monad. `reads` is a simple option, for more advanced stuff use a full-fledged parsing library like parsec.

Comment: How is `readIO` more evil than `read`? (to me it seems you're implying that)

Comment: In that it abuses `IO` for error handling that has nothing to do with IO. It is only fine if you prevent errors from happening by ensuring beforehand the parse succeeds; but then you might as well use `read` and don't need to carry around the `IO` monad.

Comment: Makes sense. I want to stress out that this is not what you'd call "production code", but code to be used where the inputs are well known and you have to refrain from including external libraries like `parsec` or `optparse-applicative` (think online coding competitions)

Comment: @berdario even then, import Text.Read and use readMaybe or just use reads. They let you handle a failed parse purely using the standard library. It's always preferable to handle errors well, even for practice code. Getting yourself in that habit is worth it.